# Convert Json String to C++ Object using Casablanca REST SDK

Tags: c++, json, casablanca

Good Morning, iam using the casablanca REST SDK.

Is there any simple way to convert a json string in an object and back as shown in this example?
(http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm)

**Update**
I found a little function that could do what i need.
When i use the function i get errors as shown in the picture. 
Have someone a solution for that?

```
User GetUser(http_request *Reques)
{
     return Request->body().extract<User>().get();
}
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TqnP.png)

greetings cazza

Comment: See response http://stackoverflow.com/a/39904347/606515 for JSON to/from C++ object conversion lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here the snipped

```
 bool User::LoadNewUser(json::value user)
{
    try{
        this->SetName(utility::conversions::to_utf8string(user[L"UserName"].as_string()));
        this->SetMail(utility::conversions::to_utf8string(user[L"Email"].as_string()));
        this->SetScreenName(utility::conversions::to_utf8string(user[L"ScreenName"].as_string()));


UserResponse Usermanagement::CreateNewUser(http_request *Request)
{
    UserResponse Resp;

    if (this->LoadNewUser(Request->extract_json().get()))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Simple Way as the is no Reflection in C++.
You must write serializing function all on your own.

However there are some tricks that may allow you to write your (de)serializing function by a list of members within macro, but Casablanca don't have any of help doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, C++ offers no simple way of blurring the line between network communication content and the source code of your program. Something like all those **terrible reflection-based** JSON libraries out there cannot happen to C++. Coincidentally, while I cannot speak for C#, reflection-based JSON libraries in Java are a huge violation of best practices outlined in Joshua Bloch's renowned [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000WJOUPA) book. See Item 53, *Prefer interfaces to reflection*:

> As a rule, objects should not be accessed reflectively in normal
>   applications at runtime

In C++, we do not need such a guideline because there is no reflection. That's mostly a *good* thing.

Now, that's not to say that you have to write your own JSON parser, of course. While JSON parsing is not part of the standard library, 3rd-party alternatives exist. For example, have a look at [JSON for Modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json).

Whatever library you use, you will have to **explicitly** read from and write to your class members in one way or the other.

That is, if you have the following class (which more or less matches the C# example you linked):

```
struct Product
{
    std::string name;
    int price;
    std::vector<std::string> sizes;
};
```

Then with the aforementioned library, you'd have to turn a `Product` object into JSON like this:

```
json j = {
    { "name", product.name },   // explicit relationship between "name" and "name"
    { "price", product.price }, // explicit relationship between "price" and "price"
    { "sizes", product.sizes }  // explicit relationship between "sizes" and "sizes"
};

std::cout << j << "\n";
```

And reading:

```
json j;
std::cin >> j;

Product product;
product.name = j["name"];   // explicit relationship between "name" and "name"
product.price = j["price"]; // explicit relationship between "price" and "price"
product.sizes = j["sizes"]; // explicit relationship between "sizes" and "sizes"
```

Such an approach is also called *non-intrusive* serialisation/deserialisation. An *intrusive* approach, on the other hand, with member or `friend` functions, would be the only way to go if you need access to private member variables.

Things to keep in mind:

- Run-time reflection is dangerous and error-prone in languages which support it.
- C++ has no run-time reflection.
- C++ encourages you to cleanly separate two concerns: (1) Parsing of JSON, (2) Serialisation/deserialisation of a class.
- Free 3rd-party libraries for JSON parsing exist.

Comment: Thanks for that advice, that helped me with my solution.