# convert my custom object into json string in Qt Framework

Tags: c++, json, qt

Is there a way to convert my custom object to json?

```
class EntityRepetitive: public EntityTreatment
{
 public:
 EntityRepetitive(int channelNum,float power,float freq,int  numOfPulses,float waitTime, int numOfTrains);
 ~EntityRepetitive();

 int channelNum;
 float power;
 float freq;
 int numOfPulses;
 float waitTime;
 int numOfTrains;
};
```

my cpp file:

```
er = new EntityRepetitive(channelNum,power,freq,numOfPulses,waitTime,numOfTrains);
```

I want to convert er to JsonString and vice versa.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting C++ class to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220130/converting-c-class-to-json)

Comment: I ask about something built-in in qt framework

Comment: Use the Qt Json classes such as [QJsonDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html) and [QJsonObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html) etc.

Comment: There is no native way in Qt. But you can declare Q_PROPERTY for each private member and pushed them to QVariantMap. QVariantMap can be converted to json via standard Qt classes, such as QJsonObject and QJsonDocument.